# In TCL, what what does if { [a 0] } mean? 'a' is defined true

Tags: tcl

I am referring tcl code of my project, I don't understand what it means.

TCL Usage:

```
if {[Variable 0] } {
  return 1
}
```

Please help!

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl5.html : "You obtain the results of a command by placing the command in square brackets ([]). This is the functional equivalent of [..] using the return value of a function in C." ..  "As the Tcl interpreter reads in a line it replaces all the $variables with their values. If a portion of the string is grouped with square brackets, then the string within the square brackets is evaluated as a command by the interpreter, and the result of the command replaces the square bracketed string."

Comment: Please **value other people's time** and consult tutorials and existing documentation. Such information, for example, can be found with a search for ["square braces tcl"](https://www.google.com/search?q=square+braces+tcl) .. less time than it took to write the question!

Comment: Variable in the above eg. was a proc defined with an argument. 
proc CONNECTED { current_stat } {
  if {a == 1}
  return 1;
}

Comment: @kammulchandani Do not add clarifying details in a comment. Please [edit] your question instead, making sure to write a clear inquiry using well-accepted terminology, orthography, and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
if {[Variable 0] } {
    return 1
}
```

is a conditional. It evaluates the *expression:*

```
[Variable 0]
```

and if that is a value considered to be true, will evaluate the *(sub-)script:*

```
return 1
```

The expression `[Variable 0]` calls the command `Variable` with the argument `0` and uses the result of the command as the result of the expression. (There's various values that can be true, but “non-zero if numeric, or the string literals `true`, `on` and `yes`” cover most of it.) The command `Variable` is not a standard Tcl command; what it does will depend on how it has been defined, but we can't help you with finding that.

The command `return 1` causes the currently-executing procedure to stop executing and successfully return the value `1`.